# What do you call a word that is an example of itself?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, "word" is a word, "adjectival" is adjectival, etc. Is there a term for this? Something like a set that includes itself, but not quite. I want to call it "autoinclusive"; would that work linguistically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is **autological** (or **homological**).

> An autological word (also called homological word) is a word expressing a property which it also possesses itself. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word)

Comment: From which we have a variant of the Grelling–Nelson paradox; "Is *autological*, autological?". If it is, then we can prove that it is. But if it isn't, then we can prove that it isn't. (The original Grelling-Nelson paradox applies to the antonym, *heterological*, asking "Is *heterological*, heterological?"; if it is then it isn't, and if it isn't then it is).